# How to proceed JSTL tags via javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have to proceed JSTL tags (fmt:) in javascript response-handler function. For example:

1. I need to switch language via AJAX, so I need update my toolpanel via javascript and in response-handler function (javascript) proceed fmt:setLocale
2. I have to update my select dropdown menus via ajax, and they must translate due localization, so I have to use fmt:message in javascript

**BUT**, jsp engine doesn't proceed .js files, and my code doesn't work:

```
document.findElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key="word_from_DB"/>";
document.findElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<fmt:setLocale value="en"/>";
```

**Question**: How can I proceed those tags from javascript or where should I search for alternative?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I need help too!

Comment: @FarazDurrani fortunatelly I stopped using JSP at all few years ago :)

Comment: lol why you say fortunately? you didn't like jsp? what do you use now?

Comment: @FarazDurrani Redux or Angular 2. I have much more fun with writing SPA applications. Also isn't JSP outdated technology?

Comment: I guess it is. But all the best. Take care. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you exactly achieve what you want depends on the contents of your JSP and JS files, but this is one potential solution:

JS:

```
function setDivInnerHTML(html1, html2) {
    document.findElementById("div1").innerHTML = html1;
    document.findElementById("div2").innerHTML = html2;
}
```

JSP:

```
...
<script>
setDivInnerHTML("<fmt:message key="word_from_DB"/>", "<fmt:setLocale value="en"/>");
</script>
...
```

**EDIT** based on comments:

JSP (URL = "/cities"):

```
String country = request.getParameter("country");
String locale = request.getParameter("locale");
List<City> cities = getCitiesFromDB(country, locale);
out.println(objectToJSON(cities));
```

JS (using jQuery):

```
function createOption(val, html) {
    return $("<option></option>").html(html).val(val);
}

function populateCities(cities) {
    var $select = $("#city_select");
    $select.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var $opt = createOption(cities[i].name, cities[i].name);
        $select.append($opt);
    }
}

function getCities(country, locale) {
    var url = "/cities";
    return $.ajax(url, {
        data: {
            country: country,
            locale: locale
        }
    });
}

// call this to load the initial cities
// and do the same thing when a new country or locale is selected
getCities(country, locale).then(populateCities);
```

Comment: but I have to pull word_from_BD from BD. For example, I have three chained select menu: in first I select country, and I need to pull into second select menu all cities< that located in the country. So, I can't wrote:
'<script>setDivInnerHTML("<fmt:message key="word_from_BD">")</script>'
Because, I don't now key value at that moment

Comment: So how are you requesting the cities at the moment? And in what format are they returned?

Comment: I requesting cities via XMLHttpRequest, and pass parameter "country". Then I query DB on the server and get ArrayList of all cities for the country. Then I return this ArrayList to handle-function in .js file via JSON.

Comment: Yes, thanks for wide example, but I still don't understand how it can help me to append city option-value due localization. How 'var $opt = createOption(cities[i].name, cities[i].name)' can help me to change cities[i].name value to three languages depends on localization?

Comment: `getCities` will load cities according to country and locale. `country` and `locale` are passed in the request. The JSP will only return cities corresponding to the country and locale, as it only asks the DB for cities according to the country and locale.

Comment: So you propose to store locale variants in DB. But, for example, in some cases you even haven't access to database, so I need to store my localization in .properties files. As I understand this approach isn't suitable for .properties files...

Comment: Ok, in that case your JSP would load the canonical city names (`getCitiesFromDB(country)`) without locale, and then you would also need to lookup the locale-specific value for that city in a properties file (`populateLocaleSpecificCityNames(cities, locale)`) before performing `objectToJSON`.

Comment: Ok, this approach is suitable for me. But should this lookup have a look of 'search for string  inside file' or I can use something like '<fmt:message key="word"/>' syntax on the server side?

Comment: Probably use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html in the JSP code. But Java code should be really be written in Java classes and not JSPs. JSPs should use as little as possible.

Comment: @PaulGrime hey Paul are you still here? I got a question too about spring tags or jstl tags. plz help!

Comment: @FarazDurrani raise a new question :)

Comment: @PaulGrime Is it possible to create new element and set its inner html to be <form:input .... path=".."...> What I mean is is it possible to create new elements and give them attributes of spring or jstl? 2nd question. If it is not possible in JSP, then what other viewing technologies have a way to do something like that? Like Apache Velocity or Thymeleaf . Thanks